# On-The-Fly Macropad?

Tags: macros, keyboard

Does anyone know of an OTF macropad out there? Like a macropad with an on the fly record button similar to what you find on razer/redragon keyboards? I'm a data scientist working for a startup still trying to get everything organized. There are many times where I have one-off, heavily repetitive tasks where automation is not a pragmatic solution. Every macropad I've seen requires you to manually write your own macros or to use some software interface, which is fine if the macros will be permanent, but mine will all be temporary. I've looked everywhere, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I am using Auto Hot Key for macros. You can select which macros and key you want run. But I dont know, If this is what are you looking for.